# Increase CPU Time Limit for processing JSON in SOAP API

Tags: apex, soap-api, connected-apps

We're using a Connected App to transfer over a big payload nightly to SF. Sometimes, the JSON payload can be pretty large. SF has some Apex code that processes this payload and can upsert the results.

When the payload is very big, we receive the following error

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "data": [
        {
            "errorCode": "APEX_ERROR",
            "message": "System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded\n\nExternal entry point"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a quick fix for this? Can we simply increase our Organization's resources?

Comment: How much big is the payload (Size), depending on that (if its max 6 MB) you can have an attachment created in SF and process that attachment via batch or synchronously.

Comment: I believe when it breaks it's over 10MB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, governor limits are global limits and cannot be increased through any means, though this limit is a *soft* limit; it can be exceeded at the discretion of the server, based on resources. Without knowing more about your system, it's hard to tell what the solution might be: writing the payload into smaller batches, using the Salesforce REST APIs instead of native Apex, or leveraging yet another server for processing (e.g. Salesforce Functions, Heroku, etc).